# Design editor is unavailable until a successful build with this error: "Failed to resolve: espresso-core"

Tags: android-studio, build

I can't open or build a project.

It says that design editor is unavailable until a successful build with this error:

> Failed to resolve: espresso-core

Someone said to add required dependencies, but I don't know how to do that (maybe because the new version is a little bit different).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As the solution from comment is solving the problem I am adding it as an answer for others:

Be sure to add Google's maven link to main build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle(app) and build.gradle(project)

Comment: The problem solved bu itself.:/ I dont know how I just opened it and saw its working://